# How to keep sprite border the same size when scaling sprite in Unity?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, sprite, photoshop, scaling

I've created an image in Photoshop to be used as a sprite in Unity and everything works fine while the sprite is scaled at X: 1; Y: 1.

The problem starts when I scale the image up as the border of the image stretches out with the rest of the image. Is there any way to scale an image from its centre or to ignore the image's border when it's scaled?

Here's the example now that I am able to show it:

[image]

The rectangle on top is the original image without being scaled up or down and the rectangle on the bottom is scaled at X:5, Y:0.5 but the borders are stretched.

I think that the borders are stretched because it's part of the image and when it's being scaled, the image (including the borders) is just being stretched.

Is there any way to stretch the sprite image but by ignoring the borders?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to scale the image and keep the original ratio?

If so, here are the steps:

[image]

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you were trying to do something else.

Comment: I'll add image examples to my original question

Comment: I will add images when I have 10 reputation :P

Comment: You could also post a link where you upload your image to a online drive.

Comment: [example](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1EF256DB552328A5!1079048&authkey=!AFyAhXMCkkYrga8&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG) - The rectangle on the top is the original sprite scaled at X:1, Y:1 and the rectangle below is when the sprite is scaled at X:5, Y:0.5 and the borders of the sprite are stretching. I know why it's happening but don't know how to get around it without removing the border altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sliced sprite. The center of the image is scaled to fit the control rectangle but the borders maintain their sizes regardless of the scaling. Check out the Unity doc here: [Unity - Manual: Image](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html)